# Core data unique entity attribute

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data

I have got entity with NSNumber like id. Then I receive web response with userProfile I create and save its entity with id. If I receive 2 the same userProfiles I have 2 entities in my base. How can I confine my base that it has only one entity with same user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always creating a new user profile when you receive data, use a fetch request to search for an existing profile. If you find one, update it and save. If you don't, then create a new one and save.

Comment: ok, thanks, I thought that there is a magic key to make entity unique

Comment: No, you would need to define merge rules for everything if that was the case (because your new instance and any relationships it had would need to be merged with any existing instance...).